# DRYer tests with associations in factory_girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, factory, functional-testing, factory-bot

Can anyone suggest a better way to make a factory use a pre-built model
instance for its association? For example, so that it would be possible
below to define a child of the Message factory so that a call to
`Factory(:my_message)` could substitute for
`Factory(:message,:sender=>@me)` ?

Sometimes the setup hash is more involved than in this contrived
example, or is just repeated in so many tests that it would seem better to push it down into the factory.

One alternative I can think of is to define a test helper method
such as `create_message_owned_by(@me)`, but I'm hoping there's a way within factory_girl itself.

factory_girl factories:

```
Factory.define :sender do |s|
  sender.name "Dummy name"
end

Factory.define :message do |msg|
  msg.text "Dummy text"
  msg.association :sender
end

Factory.define :my_message, :parent=>:message do |msg|
  msg.text "Dummy text"
  ### ? what goes here for msg.association :sender ? ###
end
```

MessagesControllerTest excerpt (using shoulda):

```
context "on GET /messages" do
  setup do
    @me = Factory(:sender)
    @my_message = Factory(:message,:sender=>@me)
    @somebody_elses_message = Factory(:message)
    sign_in_as(@me)
    get :index
  end
  should "only assign my messages" do
    assert_contains(assigns(:messages), @my_message)
    assert_does_not_contain(assigns(:messages), @somebody_elses_message)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is what you're looking for, but if you first create message you can fetch the sender through that and assign it to `@me`.

```
@my_message = Factory(:message)
@me = @my_message.sender
```

Does that help at all?

Comment: I hadn't thought of that, thanks. I can see it as a nice shorthand for other situations, but eg. here we're using the Clearance gem. @me tends to get established early and re-used on a bunch of objects, so the `@my_message = Factory(:message,:sender=>@me)` form would be shorter & clearer.

Comment: The question is, what makes the current user different from any other user? Is it just the fact that it is assigned to the @me variable? That is outside the scope of a factory and would introduce an unclear dependency.

Comment: You're right. On reflection, hard-coding @me (or similar) into the factory is dumb. The factory needs to take a parameter, which it of course does very generally as the trailing hash in the form of `Factory(:message,:sender=>@me)`.

This would seem to bring it back to abstracting out a helper like `create_message_owned_by(@me)` to wrap specific repetitive association setups.

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring for a minute the problem of creating an unclear dependency, the example above could be handled with the new callbacks in FactoryGirl 1.2.3. There are now `after_build` and `after_create` callbacks, so that you can perform operations on created objects after they already exist in the database (and have an id to grab on to, etc).

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506556/hasmany-while-respecting-build-strategy-in-factorygirl) and [this thread](http://groups.google.com/group/factory_girl/browse_thread/thread/a2f4963757ed7de4/d337a80759916404?lnk=gst&q=callback#d337a80759916404) from the factory_girl mailing list.