# FactoryGirl: Populate a has many relation preserving build strategy

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, factory-bot

My problem seems very common, but I haven't found any answer in the documentation or the internet itself.

It might seem a clone of this question [has_many while respecting build strategy in factory_girl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1506556/has-many-while-respecting-build-strategy-in-factory-girl) but 2,5 years after that post factory_girl changed a lot.

I have a model with a has_many relation called photos. I want to populate this has many relation preserving my choice of build strategy.

If I call `offering = FactoryGirl.build_stubbed :offering, :stay` I expect `offering.photos` to be a collection of stubbed models.

The only way i've found to achieve this is this one:

```
factory :offering do
  association :partner, factory: :named_partner
  association :destination, factory: :geolocated_destination

  trait :stay do
    title "Hotel Gran Vía"
    description "Great hotel in a great zone with great views"
    offering_type 'stay'
    price 65
    rooms 70
    stars 4
    event_spaces 3
    photos do
      case @build_strategy
      when FactoryGirl::Strategy::Create then [FactoryGirl.create(:hotel_photo)]
      when FactoryGirl::Strategy::Build then [FactoryGirl.build(:hotel_photo)]
      when FactoryGirl::Strategy::Stub then [FactoryGirl.build_stubbed(:hotel_photo)]
      end
    end
  end
end
```

No need to say that IT MUST EXIST a better way of do that.

Ideas?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here's a slightly cleaner version of Flipstone's answer:

```
factory :offering do
  trait :stay do
    ...
    photos do
      association :hotel_photo, :strategy => @build_strategy.class
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It seems to me this works for associations that are not has_many?

Comment: I don't think you need to specify strategy here.

Comment: Inverse does not work for me, e.g. `offering.photos.first.offering == offering` is `false`.

Answer (score 10):

You can use the various FactoryGirl callbacks:

```
factory :offering do
  association :partner, factory: :named_partner
  association :destination, factory: :geolocated_destination

  trait :stay do
    title "Hotel Gran Vía"
    description "Great hotel in a great zone with great views"
    offering_type 'stay'
    price 65
    rooms 70
    stars 4
    event_spaces 3
    after(:stub) do |offering|
      offering.photos = [build_stubbed(:hotel_photo)]
    end
    after(:build) do |offering|
      offering.photos = [build(:hotel_photo)]
    end
    after(:create) do |offering|
      offering.photos = [create(:hotel_photo)]
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: It's a better way, indeed. I was specting the existence of a method like make(:hotel_photo) that respects your preferences, but this seems good enought. Accepted

Comment: Thanks!  I removed a little duplication with `send(hook, :thing)`.  It'd be nice if this were available in a generic helper for any factory.

Comment: I've created an issue github for exposing that idea.
http://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/458

Comment: `after(:stub) do |offering|
  offering.photos = [build_stubbed(:hotel_photo)]
end`

This does not work. FactoryGirl raises the error: stubbed models are not allowed to access the database

Comment: @Jared Hmm, which version of factory girl are you using? Also, any chance you could provide a link to a gist with a reproduction of that exception?

Answer (score 3):

You can also invoke the FactoryRunner class directly and pass it the build strategy to use.

```
factory :offering do
  trait :stay do
    ...
    photos do
      FactoryGirl::FactoryRunner.new(:hotel_photo, @build_strategy.class, []).run
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have a flaw, the inverse association is not being properly initialized, e.g. `offering.photos.first.offering == offering` is `false`. Even worse that being incorrect, the `offering` is a new `Offering` for each of the `photos`.

Also, explicitly specifying a strategy is redundant.

To overcome the flow and to simplify things:

```
factory :offering do
  trait :stay do
    ...
    photos do
      association :hotel_photo, offering: @instance
    end
  end
end
```

`@instance` is an instance of the `Offering` being created by the factory at the moment. For the curious, context is `FactoryGirl::Evaluator`.

If you don't like the `@instance` like I do, you may look in `evaluator.rb` and find the following:

```
def method_missing(method_name, *args, &block)
  if @instance.respond_to?(method_name)
    @instance.send(method_name, *args, &block)
```

I really like how `itself` looks:

```
factory :offering do
  trait :stay do
    ...
    photos do
      association :hotel_photo, offering: itself
    end
  end
end
```

Do be able to use `itself`, undefine it on the `Evaluator`:

```
FactoryGirl::Evaluator.class_eval { undef_method :itself }
```

It will be passed to the `@instance` and will return the `@instance` itself.

For the sake of providing a full example with several photos:

```
factory :offering do
  trait :stay do
    ...
    photos do
      3.times.map do
        association :hotel_photo, offering: itself
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Usage:

```
offering = FactoryGirl.build_stubbed :offering, :stay
offering.photos.length # => 3
offering.photos.all? { |photo| photo.offering == offering } # => true
```

Be careful, some things might not work as expected:

- `offering.photos.first.offering_id` will surprisingly be `nil`;
- `offering.photos.count` will hit the database with a `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM hotel_photos ...` (and will return 0 in most cases), please use `length` or `size` in assertions.

Answer (score 0):

This kind of thing works for me:

```
factory :offering do
  trait :stay do
    ...
    photos { |o| [o.association(:hotel_photo)] }
  end
end
```