# Build in-test associations using Factory_girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, factory-bot, minitest

I want to be able to create associations with ID only in each specific test, trying to avoid defining them in the factory.
I've been following [Rails 4 Test Prescriptions](https://pragprog.com/book/nrtest2/rails-4-test-prescriptions)

> Avoid defining associations automatically in factory_girl definitions.
> Set them test by test, as needed. You’ll wind up with more manageable
> test data.

```
class Workspace < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :projects
end
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base  
  belongs_to :workspace
end
```

This is what I want

```
test "" do
 project_with_id = build_stubbed(:project)
 workspace_with_id = build_stubbed(:workspace)
 workspace_with_id.projects.push(project_with_id)
end
```

I am using build_stubbed to create valid ID's, which gives the following error:

> *** RuntimeError Exception: stubbed models are not allowed to access the database - Project#save({:validate=>true})

So, reading factory girl's [documentation](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/master/GETTING_STARTED.md) I came up with working associations, but I don't want to define them in the factory, not even with traits.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :project do
    association :workspace, strategy: :build_stubbed
  end
end 

test "" do
 project = build_stubbed(:project)
end
```

This works because I can call project.workspace, and both have a valid ID

**How can I create valid associations (with ID), but without touching the database,  only using Factory girl to create independent objects?**

Comment: are you using rspec?

Comment: question is tagged with minitest so its pretty safe to assume no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this if you are using `Rspec`

```
 let!(:user1) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
 let!(:user_social_profile1) { FactoryGirl.create(:user_social_profile, user_id: user1.id) }
```

also in `Rspec`

```
let!(:user1) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
let!(:user_social_profile1) { FactoryGirl.create(:user_social_profile, user: user1) }
```

In minitest/test_unit I believe

```
user1 = FactoryGirl.create(:user)
user_social_profile1 = FactoryGirl.create(:user_social_profile, user_id: user1.id)
```

I am sorry I did not explain the issues associated with using build_stubbed with factory associations, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17754770/factorygirl-build-stubbed-strategy-with-a-has-many-association) answer does a really good job at explaining that.

Comment: `create` is by far not the same thing as `build_stubbed`.

Comment: Hello phil thanks for the downvote, no one is making that argument. But there are several issues that arise when using build_stubbed in this scenario so thats why I offered an alternative to using it (that works).

Answer (score 0):

`build_stubbed` initializes a record and fakes persistence. So what you get is a record that answers true to `persisted?` and has an faked ID.

Its quite useful but the approach does not work when it comes associations as you would need to stub out large parts of ActiveRecord.

Instead you want to use `create`:

```
before do
  @project = create(:project)
  @workshop = create(:workshop, project: @project)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, you don't need an inverse to work, e.g. you'd be satisfied with `workspace.projects` being empty, wouldn't you?
This should work for you then:

```
workspace = build_stubbed(:workspace)
project = build_stubbed(:project, workspace: workspace)
```

If you need `workspace.projects`, you may use this:

```
project = build_stubbed(:project)
workspace = build_stubbed(:workspace, projects: [project])
project.workspace = workspace
```