# FactoryGirl build has_many through associations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, rspec, factory-bot

Is it possible to build associations that have a has_many through association in ActiveRecord?

Example: I have a `user` that has `team_memberships` associated with it, and those `team_memberships` have a single `team` each. So the `user` `has_many :teams, :through => :team_memberships`.

Is there a way I can build this without saving it to the database in FactoryGirl?

What I have now:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do 
    team_memberships {build_list :team_member, 1}
  end

  factory :team_member do
    id 1
    team_id 1
    user_id 1
    association :team, :strategy => :build
  end

  factory :team do
    id 1
  end
end
```

I know this is probably wrong but I'm very new to FactoryGirl. When I `build` a user on this, and then I try to do `user.teams` I get an empty array in response.

Can anyone help with this?

**UPDATE 1**

I have now also tried doing `after(:build)` blocks to setup the associations, but that doesn't seem to be working either.

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :user do 
    after(:build) { |user| user.team_memberships << build_list(:team_member, 1)}
  end

  factory :team_member do
    id 1
    team_id 1
    user_id 1
    after(:build) { |team_member| team_member.team = build(:team)}
  end

  factory :team do
    id 1
  end
end
```

Comment: This has been exhaustively answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23283955/5961578).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [FactoryGirl build\_stubbed strategy with a has\_many association](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17754770/factorygirl-build-stubbed-strategy-with-a-has-many-association)