# Unable to require neither "rails_helper" nor "spec_helper" in Rails console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am trying to get RSpec loaded in Rails console. Actually the main reason I need it is because I want to run this code so I could use "allow" syntax in FactoryBot,

```
FactoryBot::SyntaxRunner.class_eval do
  include RSpec::Mocks::ExampleMethods
end
```

So:

- I open rails console with `rails c -e test`
- I first try to run the code above directly, and get the error 
  `NameError: uninitialized constant RSpec::Mocks`
- I thought I should try to load RSpec first to get this working, so I tried running `require './spec/spec_helper'` and it shouts at me with `NoMethodError: undefined method`configure' for RSpec:Module`

As a workaround for now I just stick a `byebug` in any random place of a spec to get a hold of RSpec context with everything I need preloaded and use it instead of rails console, but is there really no better way to achieve this?

Thanks a lot in advance for any help!
P.S. a snippet from my Gemfile:

```
group :development, :test do
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug', platforms: [:mri, :mingw, :x64_mingw]
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.7.0'
  gem 'rspec-collection_matchers'
  gem 'factory_bot_rails'
end

group :test do
  # Adds support for Capybara system testing and selenium driver
  gem 'capybara', '>= 2.15', '< 4.0'
  gem 'selenium-webdriver'
  # Easy installation and use of chromedriver to run system tests with Chrome
  gem 'chromedriver-helper'
end
```

the full Gemfile is [here](https://pastebin.com/HZKUXxZt)

Comment: This sounds like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) to me. Can you please explain why your want to use RSpec Mock methods together with FactoryBot's syntax? What do you try to achieve? Can you give an example?

Comment: Cary Swoveland, so sorry, my native is Ukrainian, and in Ukrainian we do use double negative in that case. I've just realised that I should have written it as 'Unable to require either “rails_helper” or “spec_helper” in Rails console'.

Comment: spickermann, basically i wanted to use FactoryBot's "build_stubbed" for a "has_many" association. I have a class Question that has_many Answers. So I created a factory called :question_with_sample_answers:

    `factory :question_with_sample_answers do
          after(:stub) do |question, evaluator|
            allow(question).to receive(:answers).and_return(
              build_stubbed_list(:exercise_question_answer, 3, :wrong, question: question) +
                build_stubbed_list(:exercise_question_answer, 2, :correct, question: question)
            )
          end
    end`

Comment: i don't have any problems like this with FactoryBot's **create** strategy, but i struggle to get the association working with *build_stubbed* and someone suggested using RSpec's **allow** to achieve that here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17754770/factorygirl-build-stubbed-strategy-with-a-has-many-association

Comment: i followed the advice in the question above and it seemed to work fine, but I wanted to be able to use it in Rails console too so I could play with it and double check that i am actually getting what I wanted. While it is a XY question in terms that I could achieve X in some other way, I am actually interested in the Y bit: how to get RSpec loaded in Rails console. I spent long time yesterday trying to achieve that and just got curious if it's actually possible and that's why I asked specifically about loading spec_helper in Rails console

Answer (score 0):

You can require the test_helper as any ruby file.
This should work:

`require_relative 'spec/spec_helper'`